# Codeceptjs Locator Builder - is there a way to do contains comparison with withAttr?

Tags: locate, codeceptjs

I was trying to use Locator Builder (https://codecept.io/locators/#locator-builder) and noticed that when I use *withAttr*, it does a equal comparison

Ex: `locate('a').withAttr({href: '/order/offer/'})`

Translates to:
`.//a[@href = '/order/offer']`

I was looking at option where *withAttr* translates to "contains" comparison.

Ex: `.//a[contains(@href, '/order/offer')]`

Since the href has a dynamic value at the end, I had to use "contains" in my xpath. Would like to know if there is a similar option with Location Builder

Note: I saw that *withText* does a contains comparison

Answer (score 1):

you can use something like

```
locate('a[href^='/order/offer/']')
```

This will translate to
`.//a[starts-with(@href,'/order/offer')]`

Answer (score 0):

No, you can't do it with locator builder since only developers of this feature can define how it work. You can do a feature request, but from my experience this feature are not widely used so most probably they will not improve it or create a new command.

Answer (score 0):

You are probably looking for [Custom Locators](https://codecept.io/locators/#custom-locators).

```
// inside a plugin or a bootstrap script:
codeceptjs.locator.addFilter((providedLocator, locatorObj) => {
    if (typeof providedLocator === 'string') {
      // this is a string
      if (providedLocator[0] === '=') {
        locatorObj.value = `.//*[text()="${providedLocator.substring(1)}"]`;
        locatorObj.type = 'xpath';
      }
    }
});
```

This translates to:

```
I.click('=Login');
```

You can be pretty creative with it.